# Failed to connect Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect while registering SeleniumGrid Node to Hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

Selenium hub is up and running on Windows desktop, set up Windows VM to be node. Node won't register to hub.

Step 1:
Entered command in Windows Desktop:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub -port 2222`

Output:

```
`11:11:24.171 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
11:11:24.175 INFO [GridLauncherV3$2.launch] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 2222
11:11:25.108:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2242ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
11:11:26.832 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
11:11:26.832 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://172.20.111.25:2222/grid/register/
11:11:26.832 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://172.20.111.25:2222/wd/hub`
```

Checked the config page on localhost and saw that it was there.

Step 2: 
Entered this into the command line in Windows Virtual Machine:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://172.20.111.25:2222/grid/register`

Output:

`10:18:43.108 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
10:18:43.155 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 18004
2019-06-03 10:18:43.676:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1482ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
10:18:44.108 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 18004
10:18:44.108 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
10:18:44.280 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
10:18:44.280 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://172.20.111.25:2222/grid/register
10:19:06.003 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to /172.20.111.25:2222`

Comment: Was that the actual IP or you handcrafted it for the sake of demonstration? By any means **`178.90.666.34`** doesn't looks to be a valid IP. Can you cross check once?

Comment: Just updated to the actual IP.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've updated the post to reflect following your answer from top to bottom, it is still failing to connect to the hub.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You need to remove the additional *forward slash* (i.e. **`/`**) at the end of the *registration uri* while registering the *Selenium Grid Node* and you can use the following steps:

- First of all, to start the *Selenium Grid Hub* on *port* **2222** you need to issue the following command:

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub -port 2222
  ```
- You will find the following logs generated:

  ```
  16:00:50.746 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
  16:00:50.750 INFO [GridLauncherV3$2.launch] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 2222
  2019-05-31 16:00:51.392:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1151ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  16:00:52.139 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
  16:00:52.141 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.125:2222/grid/register/
  16:00:52.141 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.125:2222/wd/hub
  ```
- Now you can access the **Selenium Grid Console** through the URL:

  ```
  http://localhost:2222/grid/console
  ```
- The console will look like:

[image: SeleniumGridConsole]

- Now finally to start the *Selenium Grid Node* you have to issue the following command:

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:2222/grid/register
  ```
- You will find the following logs generated:

  ```
  16:04:48.440 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
  16:04:48.470 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Launching a Selenium Grid node onport 7724
  2019-05-31 16:04:48.985:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1059ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  16:04:49.275 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 7724
  16:04:49.275 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
  16:04:49.454 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
  16:04:49.454 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.125:2222/grid/register
  16:04:50.355 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
  ```

Comment: Removing the / didn't solve the error. When I ran it without the / at the end of register I still got an error: "Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts." "Failed to connect to /xxx.xxx.xxx.xx: Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /xx.xxx"

Comment: @lydi Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @lydi Can you update the question with all the 5 parts (commands and logs generated) within the main question for further analysis. Additionally, instead of using the minor release jar of **selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar** can you try with major release jar of **`selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar`**?

Comment: What's the difference between using a major or minor release jar?

Comment: @lydi Great, you can change the **xxx.xx.xx** to their actual values. No harm in that. That may help me somehow.

Comment: I just tried using the selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar and the error output was the same.

Comment: @lydi Check out the updated answer and follow the sequence, i.e first the **Selenium Grid Hub** and finally the **Selenium Grid Node** and let me know the status.

Comment: The status is the same. The problems arise when I run the Node command in the virtual machine. The virtual machine is running an older version of Windows, would this have an effect on the node connecting to the hub?

Comment: @lydi No, it shouldn't. Try to establish the connection on your local host first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go through the steps mentioned below through which I am successfully able to resolve that issue.

1. Login to other machine and register it as a node.
2. Ping IP from both the machines to check whether you're on a same network.
3. Verify that Windows Defender Firewall should be off to ping machine when you're trying on a same network.
4. In Node Machine , Download standalone jar and paste in some directory and open cmd from that directory .
5. Verify whether you're able to check URL in Node machine
   Ex: URL : http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/grid/console
6. Run the command :

```sh
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I believe I fixed this error.

So I started the hub from my desktop: 172.17.248.33

and then I tried to connect the node from my virtual machine: 173.248.137.73 back to my desktop 172.17.248.33.

I knew beforehand that when I started the hub from my desktop and then ran a node on my desktop it would connect.

However, I was under the impression I could start the hub in my desktop 172.17.248.33 and then have my VM node 173.248.137.73 connected to the hub desktop. I am guessing this is not possible with Selenium.

Once I started the hub from my virtual machine and initiated the node command from the same machine, it worked.